# iOS 9 utilize both split screens from one app

Tags: ios, ios9, split-screen

I work on an app which uses multiple views very often. The users workflow will make them switch between different tabBar tabs all the time.

When using it in a potential live environment, this would be really disrupting.

iOS 9 is quite promising because of the new split screen feature.
So would it be possible to display two instances of `UIScreen` and place both of them in an individual screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the iPad Pro simulator for a bit, I can tell you that your app will not be able to use both sides of the split screen.

If you want to use all of the screen space you could consider using UIPageViewController with two page view controllers for the left and right sides.

Comment: What about Safari and co? They are using both screens at the same time. It came into my mind when I was thinking about it again...

Comment: I haven't seen that. But seriously, it's not going to work. You get to run on one side.